# Continuous delivery of infrastructure projects

Tags: jenkins, vagrant, lxc, continuous-delivery, test-kitchen

I'm using Jenkins to achieve Continuous Delivery on some infrastructure projects. ATM Master-Slave Jenkins model is used where the jobs are always built by some some slave and not by the master, my intentions are to build and run test-kitchen and leibniz tests using LXC. All the requirements are matched vagrant-lxc, lxc boxes, leibniz and test-kitchen configured, everything works ok on my PC or any other of my team members but when it comes to run the Job through Master-Slave on Jenkins it seems there are some problems with environment, in details:

1- When I run as part of a build step `"which lxc-create"` it works and shows `/usr/bin/lxc-create` as it should but

2- When it runs `kitchen test` is fails showing:

```
+ kitchen test
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.1.1)
-----> Cleaning up any prior instances of <default-ubuntu-1204>
-----> Destroying <default-ubuntu-1204>...
       Finished destroying <default-ubuntu-1204> (0m0.00s).
-----> Testing <default-ubuntu-1204>
-----> Creating <default-ubuntu-1204>...
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: Failed to complete #create action: [Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider=lxc ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: The `lxc` package does not seem to be installed or is not accessible on the PATH.
---- End output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider=lxc ----
Ran vagrant up --no-provision --provider=lxc returned 1]
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
```

It seems some environment variable is missing or something wired, It matters to say that sshing into the slave and building manually it works fine so is not a setup problem but a Master-Slave environment transmission problem or I'm missing something crucial on the configurations. Can anyone provide some help?

lxc version: 1.0.0

vagrant-lxc: 0.8.0

jenkins: 1.5.49

UPDATE 1:
Here is my kitchen configuration:

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  require_chef_omnibus: false
  require_chef_berkshelf: true
  customize:
      memory: 1024

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-12.04
    driver:
      box: "ubuntu-12.04"
      box_url: "http://dl.company.com/ubuntu1204-lxc-amd64.box"
      provider: lxc

suites:
  ....
```

Comment: What user is running `kitchen` vs `lxc-create`. Do you have the kitchen-lxc driver? Why is vagrant involved, that's unclear to me.

Comment: @sethvargo Jenkins is running "kitchen test" with Vagrant driver and LXC provider for vagrant. To clarify, I have added a step wich runs "which lxc-create" just to check if Jenkins slave environment can run lxc-create and it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue!. The error message raised by Jenkins was wrong, I added Jenkins user to sudoers with NOPASSWORD and it worked just fine. I figured out because on my personal PC creating a container always asks for the sudo password.